# State is not updating after reducer is updating the state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get data from App.js for network connection availability. I'm getting data from App.js to action and reducer but the reducer is not updating the state for my component. The console log in the reducer is working but I'm not able to get data in the mapStateToProps of myComponent.
My App.js file contains this code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import Router from './src/Router';
import { internetConnectionChanged } from './src/actions/';

class App extends Component {
 componentWillMount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);
 }

componentWillUnmount() {
 NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
 NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
(isConnecteds) => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
  store.dispatch(internetConnectionChanged(isConnecteds));  
});
};
render() {
 const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
  return (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router />
  </Provider>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

My code in action file is

```
import { CONNECTION_CHANGE } from '../actions/types';

export const internetConnectionChanged = (isConnected) => {
 return {
   type: CONNECTION_CHANGE,
  payload: isConnected
 };
};
```

That is exported via the index.js of actions file 
through `export * from './AppActions';`

Code for the reducer is

```
import { CONNECTION_CHANGE } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { isConnected: false };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case CONNECTION_CHANGE:
  console.log(action.payload);
  return { ...state, isConnected: action.payload };
  default:
  return state;
 }
};
```

Under my component, this is the code to get the info is

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, app }) => {
const { email, password, error, loading } = auth;
const { isConnected } = app;
return { email, password, error, loading, isConnected };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
 emailChanged,
 passwordChanged,
 loginUser,
 forgotPasswordAction,
 })(LoginForm);
```

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(this.props) in LoginFrom component? Do you get the other states, mapped correctly?

Comment: @Shivam Yes I'm getting the correct state from reducers and only initial state of the appreducer that is false

Comment: Have you checked that, isConnected state is really getting updated in the store? Like when we use redux logger it shows us previous and next state.

Comment: You're creating a new `store` on each event and each render. Try it with a single `const store =  ..` outside of class `App`.

Comment: @Shivam in the store means in the login component? Sry for the question but I'm not able to understand the question. I'm able to get the value in the reducer. but not in the login component mapstatetoprops.

Comment: yup, as @Oblosys said you need to createStore outside the class.

Comment: @Oblosys Can you please tell me how can I create store outside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create store outside the App class. This might be causing the store to always have initial reducer values. Just paste the below line before `Class App extends Component` line

```
 const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
```

Also remove the same above line of code from the following function

```
handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
 NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
(isConnecteds) => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)); //remove this line
  store.dispatch(internetConnectionChanged(isConnecteds));  
});
};
```